# How to add "-" in between two stings on Android?

Tags: java, android, string

Example: 
`cname = "name"`
`ccurt = "last name"`

Required output = `name - last name`
But current output = `namelast name`

How to get output as above? The used code is below for your reference,

Code used:

```
long id= AddDbHelper.createReminder(cname +ccurt,de,reminderDateTime);
```

Comment: Please take care of the formatting. I also find it difficult to understand what you are asking for especially when looking at the question in the title...

Comment: U Have UR own Question answer just need to do +"-"+  ,

long id= AddDbHelper.createReminder(cname +"-"+ccurt,de,reminderDateTime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
String output=cname+"-"+ccurt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(); 
tmp.append(cname);
tmp.append("-");
tmp.append(ccurt);
String fullName = tmp.toString();
```

Or simply:

```
String fullName = new StringBuilder(cname).append(" - ").append(ccurt).toString();
```

---

[StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

> A modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating strings. This
>   class is intended as a direct replacement of StringBuffer for
>   non-concurrent use; unlike StringBuffer this class is not
>   synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

String output=cname+" - "+ccurt;